# Не удается найти класс

Tags: php, yii2, telegram-bot, telegram

Пытаюсь встроить в Yii2 приложение официальное API Telegram:

```
use unreal4u\TelegramAPI\TgLog;
use unreal4u\TelegramAPI\Telegram\Methods\SetWebhook; // <<<<<<
use unreal4u\TelegramAPI\Telegram\Types\Update;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $setWebhook = new SetWebhook(); // Class not found
        ...
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Class 'unreal4u\TelegramAPI\Telegram\Methods\SetWebhook' not found

Ссылка на проблемный класс: https://github.com/unreal4u/telegram-api/blob/master/src/Telegram/Methods/SetWebhook.php

Comment: Если ставили через Composer - должен был сгенерится autload, и его перед всем этим хозяйством нужно сделать include_ince/reuire_once

Comment: @chernomyrdin по сколько этот класс `TelegramController` я наследую от `Controller`, он является частью Yii приложения, по этому, autoload должен подтягиваться. По крайней мере, раньше я ни разу не подтягивал autoload  руками.

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации (https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api) :

```
<?php 

class TelegramController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
        try {
            $bot = $this->getInstance();
            ...
}

protected function getInstance()
    {
        $telegram_bot_key = '';
        return  new \TelegramBot\Api\BotApi($telegram_bot_key);
    }
}
```